# How does readyState work?

Tags: ajax, cross-browser, pageload, readystate

I check the property `.readyState` of `BrowserTestObject` using RFT (Rational Functional Tester).

Sometimes before the next step in my test script I need to be sure that the page is 'ready' and all objects are loaded.

Does the `.readyState == 4` mean that **all objects within the browser are loaded and ready**? Could any **ajax call** in background be still "working" or it must finish before the browser returns `.readyState=4`? What about a flex application?

Is that behavior browser independent or not really? I am after IE 8 (and firefox 3.6.x)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

quick answer is YES if browser implementation is correct.

See here: http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/dom.html#current-document-readiness

Comment: @Radek, according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535874(v=vs.85).aspx, IE8 has a buggy implementation. FF 3.6 supports it because the bug is fixed at https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=347174.

Comment: Even in IE9, the bug is not totally gone away: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536957(v=vs.85).aspx. I suggest to tackle your requirements in a different way. Maybe you don't have to know "all are objects loaded"? Maybe a different design on the Ajax calls will help.

Answer (score 2):

I would say no. If I understood discussion [here](https://community.ibm.com/community/user/legacy?messageID=14253612), readyState used thus only refers to the test javascript, nothing else. To wait that the document itself is loaded, you need to hook to `document.readyState` and wait for it to become `"complete"`. In that case, once the HTML parsing is complete, the `document.readyState` would be `"complete"` once and for all, and will not be affected by any XMLHttpRequest whatsoever. Flash plugins could or could not have started; most certainly there would be lots of javascript running; for example `$(function() {})` construct in jquery often means that javascript code could start executing only after the browser hits the "complete" state.

To test if any asynchronous requests are going on, I suggest hooking the readyState event of all XMLHttpRequests somehow and make it update a global variable.